# Does Civ V have a map editor?

Tags: civilization-5

> <strike>Wait, a non Witcher question? For shame!</strike>

Now that Civ V's been out for a while, I thought I would repurpose part of the game. Simply put, I'd love to use the rendered terrain to create hex-based maps for use in other areas, for instance, with my D&D group.

However, I can't seem to find a stand alone version of a map editor of any sort. The last Civ game I owned, Civ III, had a stand alone program to edit the maps, but I haven't found anything similar for Civ V. Does Civ V have a dedicated map editor? And if it's not a stand alone program, how do I access it in the first place?

Comment: I chuckled pretty hard at the non-witcher question bit. I found it a bit odd when suddenly 90% of the new questions were about some game I've never heard of.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>Assuming you use Steam</strike>*:

> First of all you’ll need to download the Civilization V world builder itself. Open up Steam and head to the **Tools** section of your games library, find *Sid Meier’s Civilization V SDK* and install it. Once the small download has finished you can launch the SDK at any time straight from this menu.

http://www.pcgamer.com/2010/10/13/how-to-make-a-map-in-civilization-v/

<sub>*Civ 5 is Steam-only I hear, my bad.</sub>

Comment: Aha, so it was hiding under tools. That'll do it. Thanks!

Comment: @Raven Sure thing. I loved making horribly skewed maps back in the days of Civ II :P

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Not really a surprise, that's where the level editors for Valve's own games hide, too!

Comment: I tried that, but it said its not supported by my current platform.